# Numbers not selectable for XeTeX output with Source Han Serif

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm trying to use Source Han Serif (otf) as my main font with XeTex (through LyX), but numbers in the output pdf is not selectable. Some other otf font, Cabin for example, works well with selectable number in the output. Moreover, Source Han Sans can output selectable numbers as well, which makes no sense to me.

Belows are exported permeable:

```
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,english,UTF8]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.5in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue,pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\setmainfont[Mapping=none, ItalicFont=Source Han Serif SC, ItalicFeatures=FakeSlant, AutoFakeSlant]{Source Han Serif SC}
\setsansfont[Mapping=none]{Source Han Sans SC}
\setmonofont{Courier 10 Pitch}
\setCJKmainfont[
BoldFont=Source Han Serif SC, BoldFeatures=FakeBold,
ItalicFont=Source Han Serif SC, ItalicFeatures=FakeSlant]{Source Han Serif SC}%
\setCJKsansfont[
BoldFont=Source Han Sans SC, BoldFeatures=FakeBold,
ItalicFont=Source Han Sans SC, ItalicFeatures=FakeSlant]{Source Han Sans SC}

% Define hyphenation
\pretolerance=500
\tolerance=9000
\emergencystretch=0pt
\righthyphenmin=4
\lefthyphenmin=4

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

Also, about my XeTeX version:

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 55.1; using 55.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.5; using 2.5.5
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.6; using 1.3.10
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 1.0.1; using 1.0.1
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.17; using 1.6.17
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.1; using 2.11.94
```

This font can be download here:
https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/blob/release/OTF/SimplifiedChinese/SourceHanSerifSC-Regular.otf

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I couldn't compile using xelatex (mainly because I don't use it and I can't make it find the fonts in Linux), but using lualatex (from TeXLive 2018) it works fine and the numbers are selectable. You might want to consider updating your TeXLive distribution, 2015 was a long time ago.